# Parsing shopping websites usign jsoup

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup, html-parser

I have the following code:

```
doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.amazon.com/gp/goldbox").userAgent("Mozilla").timeout(5000).get();

  Elements hrefs = doc.select("div.a-row.layer");
  System.out.println("Results:"+ hrefs); //I am trying to print out contents but not able to see the output.
```

Problem: Want to display all image src within the div with class name "a-row layer". But, i am unable to see the output.

What is the mistake with my query?

Answer (score 0):

I have taken a look at the website and tested it myself. The issue seems to be that the piece of html code you want to extract (`div.a-row.layer`) is generated by **JavaScript**.

Jsoup does not support JavaScript and cannot parse those generated by it. You would need a **headless web browser** to deal with this, such as [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.